# Can I connect to other computers on my network using FTP?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ftp

Is there a way to connect to other computers on my home wifi network via FTP using something such as Filezilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can access the FTP service running on other computers, either use a client like `filezilla` or mount remote FTP folders as file system by using `curlftpfs`, similar to `sshfs`.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-ftp-folder-to-local-directory-in-ubuntu.html

Classic GNOME has a GUI tool does similar thing:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22518/how-to-mount-a-remote-folder-in-ubuntu/

Comment: When I try to connect via FTP I get "connection refused"

Comment: Is there any firewall (iptables) blocking traffic？ Especially on the FTP server side.

Comment: how to get list of network pc in filezilla ??

Comment: @Gomzy I think you are talking about SMB?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfbHj.png  see this link @TerryWang